# Нужна ли запятая после "дождя"?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены

Ей была по душе такая погода. Глядя на тяжелые, полные дождя тучи, на покрытые сумраком улицы, Асмантус всегда ощущала умиротворение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уточняющие определения, обстоятельства обособляются с двух сторон. В данном предложении ***тяжёлые, полные дождя*** — однородные определения, второе из которых не несёт уточняющего характера. Скорее, это пояснение, то есть обозначение одного и того же другими словами. Поэтому запятая не нужна.

[**Пояснительные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119) (Розенталь):

> **Примечания:**
>
> 2. Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова *а именно, то есть* и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится: *Торчали толстые головни, остатки **прежней, сгоревшей** бани* (М. Г.); ***Очередной, шестой** том подписного издания на днях поступит в магазин*; *Он заговорил совсем **другим, серьёзным** тоном.*